# Is there any point to this code that translates a strftime into a time and then back into a string?

Tags: perl, datetime

I am converting some scripts from Perl to Python. I have a piece of code that looks weird.

```
my $dt         = DateTime->now->subtract( days => 1 );
my $start_time = $dt->strftime("%Y-%m-%d");
# ... <some code here>
my $epoch = str2time( $start_time, "GMT" );
my $start_dt = DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => $epoch );
my $start_date = $start_dt->strftime("%Y-%m-%d");
```

And here I have a question about `start_time` and `start_date`.

Does it make sense to perform these last three lines?

UPDATE:

@darch asked to add any useful code related to `start_time`. I don't think it is useful, but here it is (removed not significant lines):

```
my %opts;
my $opt_string = 'ahropuc:i:s:e:t:';
getopts( "$opt_string", \%opts );

my $start_time = $dt->strftime("%Y-%m-%d");

if ( $opts{a} ) {
    if ( $opts{s} ) {
        $start_time = $opts{s};
    }
}

my $epoch = str2time( $start_time, "GMT" );
my $start_dt = DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => $epoch );
my $start_date = $start_dt->strftime("%Y-%m-%d");
```

The only reasonable answer is validation as answered below.

I am going to rewrite this part to exclude user input, so if it is and this part is meaningless - I simply cut it.

Comment: It *can* be reassigned from the command-line parameter, but I think it is expected to be of the same format. Command-line parameter might be not passed, so the variable remains unchanged until these 3 lines.

Comment: There are different `str2time`s that could be used.  Is this one being imported from `Date::Parse` or some other library?

Comment: I am not so familiar with Perl, but in the beginning I see `use DateTime; use Date::Parse;`. Have no idea where it can be imported from also.

Comment: Added some more code, but I don't think it is helpful.

Comment: The addition shows that my answer below is definitively wrong.

Comment: Really? I removed the mark, you can withdraw it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalization.  Those lines are providing normalization of user input.

You see, `Date::Parse::str2time` can accept input in a [wide variety of formats](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/TimeDate-2.30/lib/Date/Parse.pm#EXAMPLE_DATES) .  By parsing the user input and then turning it back into a string, we can guarantee that we use a consistent format internally.

The existing code can be restructured into this equivalent formulation:

```
my %opts;
my $opt_string = 'ahropuc:i:s:e:t:';
getopts( "$opt_string", \%opts );

my $start_time;

# use the time specified on the command line or 'yesterday'
if ( $opts{a} and $opts{s} ) {
    my $start_time_string = $opts{s};
    my $epoch = Date::Parse::str2time( $start_time_string, "GMT" );
    $start_time = DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => $epoch );
} else {
    $start_time = DateTime->now->subtract( days => 1 );
} 

# should be called $start_date_string, but keep the old name
# so that we could just drop this code into place
my $start_date = $start_time->strftime("%Y-%m-%d");
```

If you are not worried about accepting user input, you should be able to safely remove the lines that perform the normalization.